# Syntax error trying to ALTER TABLE using variable

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to add a section that can add extra columns to a table so I am trying a parametrised `ALTER TABLE` query. However when I run it I am getting an error :

> SQL logic error near "@TableName":syntax error

Code:

```
public void addNewField(string tableName, string newFieldName, string dataType)
{
    SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionStrings.getSQLiteDBConnectString());
    string sql = @"ALTER TABLE @TableName ADD @NewFieldName @dataType";
    dbConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tableName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewFieldName", newFieldName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataType", dataType);
    try
        {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Why am I getting the error? I tried different field names and have run the SQL string (with @ variables replaced) in a part of my application that allows to run free typed queries and the base query worked.

Comment: you can't parameterise DDL without resort to dynamic SQL. The fact an app wants to dynamically add columns to a table is in most cases an odd use case

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Its intended to give customisation to the application. I suppose a bit like an IDE just for the application iteself.

Comment: Consider putting the customization in a single existing column storing the data as json that contains the new custom columns inside it.

Answer (score 1):

With SQLite, the only kind of parameterization possible is parameterized values in DQL/DML statements. It is not possible to provide any database object identifier names as query parameters to any kind of statements.

Parameterization is intended to separate user-supplied values from the SQL code. And the user should not be provided with ability to change the schema. Otherwise, RDBMS may not be a good fit for your application.